# Where is the OpenJDK Implementation of sun.management.ThreadImpl#findDeadlockedThreads0

Tags: jvm, java.util.concurrent, java

I am trying to find the OpenJDK (7 or 8) implementation for `sun.management.ThreadImpl#findDeadlockedThreads0` as I want to understand how it locates all the `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock`s in a system and interrogates them to find deadlocks.

I realise this is implemented in Native code, however having browsed the Mercurial repository for OpenJDK 7, I am struggling to find the real C/C++ code that does this.

I managed to get as deep as this - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/native/sun/management/ThreadImpl.c#l112

But I can't seem to find the implementation of `jmm_interface->FindDeadlocks`. Can anyone put me on the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation is in the JVM part, see:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/modules/hotspot/file/9646293b9637/src/share/vm/services/management.cpp#l1795